# Dar un formato especifico a un campo date en un gridview asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Alguien sabe como dar formato a un fila de `gridview` mediante el `codehebing`

He estado intentando con esto pero no me logra salir :

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[2].Text = e.Row.Cells[2].Text.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");




              e.Row.Cells[1].Visible = false;
                 e.Row.Cells[3].Visible = false;
              e.Row.Cells[5].Visible = false;
              e.Row.Cells[6].Visible = false;
              e.Row.Cells[7].Visible = false;
              e.Row.Cells[8].Visible = false;
              e.Row.Cells[10].Visible = false;
              e.Row.Cells[12].Visible = false;
               e.Row.Cells[14].Visible = false;
              e.Row.Cells[15].Visible = false;
               e.Row.Cells[16].Visible = false;
                e.Row.Cells[18].Visible = false;
                e.Row.Cells[19].Visible = false;
                e.Row.Cells[20].Visible = false;
               e.Row.Cells[21].Visible = false;
               e.Row.Cells[22].Visible = false;
              e.Row.Cells[23].Visible = false;



        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Pierro, cambia la imagen por el texto del mensaje que muestra la advertencia. Un saludo

Comment: Lo primero que debes saber es que tipo de datos contiene esa columna. Es `string` o `DateTime`?

Comment: @Pikoh esque en ese datagrid yo no se que contiene no se si es string o Datetime

Comment: @lois6b si el mensaje sale este errror :
 Error 3 La mejor coincidencia de método sobrecargado para 'string.ToString(System.IFormatProvider)' tiene algunos argumentos no válidos

Comment: @lois6b ahi esta mi hermano

Comment: @lois6b esta aqui : protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)

Comment: @lois6b listo ya entendi

Comment: No, no entendiste. Mira mi **primer comentario**

Comment: @lois6b ya cambie mi imagen y puse el texto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder darle un formato primero lo que realize en convertir en un LINQ al gridview.

```
  listadtodividendo = tabla.ConsultarTablaAmortizacion(dtorequest).ToList();
var nuevolistadtodividendo = (from o in listadtodividendo
                select new {
                    NumeroCuota = o.NumeroCuota,
                    FechaVencimiento = o.FechaVencimiento.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"),
                      Cuota = o.Cuota,
                    AmortizacionCapital = o.Capital, o.CapitalReducido,
                    Interes = o.Interes,
                    Saldo = o.CapitalReducido //o.Capital

                }).ToList();
```

y para que solo forme la fecha que debe de ser Año - Mes - Dia

**FechaVencimiento = o.FechaVencimiento.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"),**

Answer (score 1):

Debes tener una tipo de dato `DateTime` para poder aplicar fomato

```
e.Rows[2].Text = Convert.ToDateTime(e.Rows[2].Text).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

Para asegurar el tipo de dato tambien se aplica

```
DateTime fecha;
if(DateTime.TryParse(e.Rows[2].Text, out fecha)){
    e.Rows[2].Text = fecha.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
}
```

Aunque si defiens las columnas en tiempo de diseño quedaria aun mejor

[Format DateTime in GridView BoundField and TemplateField columns in ASP.Net](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Format-DateTime-in-GridView-BoundField-and-TemplateField-columns-in-ASPNet.aspx)

basicamente defines en el `BoundField`

```
DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"
```

Comment: +1 por la propiedad `DataFormatString`.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacer lo siguiente

```
Datetime fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(e.Row.Cells[2]);
e.Row.Cells[2].Text = fecha.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
```